# Can I convert the format of date in varchar using php?

Tags: php, date, format

I have a date in my column that is varchar(30) and in my table it appears the format **d/m/y** I want to convert it to **m/d/y**

I try this but wont work. please help.

```
$test = new DateTime('date');
echo '<td>' .date_format($test, 'm-d-Y').$row.'</td>';
```

Comment: First mistake: Storing a date as a varchar. You should have stored it as an actual date/datetime/timestamp value instead, and then your question would be trivial.

Comment: I tried to stored it as a date but the output becomes **0000-00-00**

Comment: mysql date strings must be in `yyyy-mm-dd hh:mm:ss` format. you can't stuff in any random string you want and expect mysql to figure out what it is.e.g. what's `01/02/03`? Jan 2nd, 2003? March 1st, 2002?

Comment: I've already solved the problem and thanks to user4013047.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `DateTime::createFromFormat` and `DateTime::format`:

```
$date = DateTime::createFromFormat('d/m/y', $row['date']);
echo $date->format('m/d/y');
```

Answer (score 0):

you can use:

```
echo date("m-d-Y",strtotime($row['date']));
```

example:

```
echo date("m-d-Y",strtotime("8/7/2014"));
```

where `$row['date']` is date fetched from db table.

Comment: i need to get the date from my column 'date'

Comment: yes this will help if you are using fetch assoc. string totime function will convert any valid date string into unix timestamp. This is excepted by date function which will convert it into required date format.

Comment: the format is working but the problem is all the date appears **12-31-1969** that's not in my database

Comment: seems that it does not fetching the data. please help

Comment: how you are fetching data from db and please post output of $row i.e. print_r($row)

Comment: I dont get it. sorry. please explain what to do

Comment: Or else you can use $date = DateTime::createFromFormat('d/m/Y', $row['date']);
echo $date->format('m/d/Y');

Comment: Thankyou!! it finally works